# Can existing WPF applications be converted to MonoDroid easily?

Tags: xamarin.android

Is there any automated conversion which will take an existing WPF application and convert it to MonoDroid?  Leveraging existing knowledge of C# is great.  What would be the icing on the cake would be being able to continue writing WPF XAML code as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no support for WPF.

While you can share business logic between .Net/MonoDroid/MonoTouch, the only supported UI is the native UI on each device, so you will need to write a different UI for each platform.